# Drupal hook_form_alter anonymous user can't see the fields

Tags: drupal, forms, permissions, hook, alter

I created a small module for altering forms called "form_mods". The form I'm altering is the "user_profile_form". I added a category for extra fields called "Profile". 
I created a select field in the Drupal admin called "profile_state" and I'm altering it in my module to have a key => value list of states and It's working for me when logged in as an admin but an anonymous user that's trying to register sees an empty states select field. Is there a permissions issue here? I tried to add 'access' => user_access('access content') to the field but that didn't work. Here is my code:

```
function form_mods_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {

    switch ($form_id) {

        ##  user_profile_form  ###################################################################################
        case 'user_profile_form': // This is our form ID.

            //echo '###'.$form['_category']['#value'].'###';
            if($form['_category']['#value'] == 'Profile'){  

                // Modify the states dropdown list
                $states = load_states_list();   
                $form['Profile']['profile_state'] = array(
                  '#type' => 'select',
                  '#title' => t('State'),
                  '#options' => $states,
                  '#required' => TRUE,
                  '#default_value' => isset($form['Profile']['profile_state']['#default_value']) ? $form['Profile']['profile_state']['#default_value'] : '',
                  '#element_validate' => array('profile_state_validate')
                );

            }
        ####################################################################################
        break;

    }   

}

function load_states_list() {

    $states = array('' => '-- Select a state'); // add a default empty value
    $results = db_query("SELECT * FROM {states_list} ORDER BY name ASC");
    while ($state = db_fetch_array($results)) {
      $states[$state['code']] = $state['name'];
    }

    return $states;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Not to dig up an old question, but if this is resolved, can you mark mine as the answer?  It's gotten several up votes by now, and solved the issue at hand.  I'm trying to clean up my loose hanging answers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, are you sure you're function ever gets run?  Having the function named the way you do, I don't think it is.  If the module name is "form_mods", your function should be called

```
function form_mods_form_alter
```

Or...since you're only modifying the user_profile_form form, you could use the function name

```
function form_mods_user_profile_form_alter
```

Now, the reason it isn't working is because you don't have the & in front of the $form in the parameter list.  The & basically passes the variable as reference, and so any changes you make to the $form variable will be saved and passed back to the calling function.  So, your function should look like

```
function form_mods_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
```

OR

```
function form_mods_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
```

Reference: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6

Answer (score -2):

Thank you mikesir87 for the reference link. I figured out my problem.
There are 2 different forms that are using those fields I created. They have different form id's. I have to look for "user_profile_form"  and "user_register" form id's.

Here is my new code that works:

```
function form_mods_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {

    if( (($form_id == 'user_profile_form') && ($form['_category']['#value'] == 'Profile')) || ($form_id == 'user_register') ){

            // Modify the states dropdown list
            $states = form_mods_load_states_list(); 
            $form['Profile']['profile_state'] = array(
              '#type' => 'select',
              '#title' => t('State'),
              '#options' => $states,
              '#required' => TRUE,
              '#default_value' => isset($form['Profile']['profile_state']['#default_value']) ? $form['Profile']['profile_state']['#default_value'] : ''
            );

    }

}
```

thanks

Comment: please update your original post.  Also, it looks like you didn't rename your function correctly.  if that function lives in "form_mods" module you have created, the function should be called form_mods_form_alter()

Comment: Thanks Erik. It's corrected now. Do you mean I update my original post with my solution instead of answering it? thanks